# The consolidated results containing only one item, while expecting to have more than one

Tags: javascript

**Question:**

Sorry if I cant summarize the problem in a nut shell, so I try to explain it in details.
I try to construct a object by using a input. However my consolidated results containing only one item, while expecting to have more than one.

Q2:In addition to the bug, may I seek for a answer that could avoid issue with array manipulation when I try to copy value from one array to a new variable, then change the value in it?

**Problem:**

Input:

```
[ { name: 'Balanced',
    allocations: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'Balanced Plus',
    currency: 'GBP',
    allocations: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'Conservative',
    currency: 'GBP',
    allocations: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'Growth',
    currency: 'GBP',
    allocations: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'Income',
    currency: 'GBP',
    allocations: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

Expected output:

```
{ US: { allocation: { Balanced: [Array] , Balanced Plus: [Array],  Conservative: [Array],  Growth: [Array], Income: [Array]}  } }
```

Result:

```
{ US: { allocation: { Income: [Array] } } }
```

**Below is my present code:**

```
const a = [
  {
    name: "Balanced",
    allocations: [
      {
        id: "2241",

      },
      {
        id: "1175",
       
      },
      {
        id: "2269",
       
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Balanced Plus",
    currency: "GBP",
    allocations: [
      {
        id: "2238",
      
      },
      {
        id: "1175",
       
      },
      {
        id: "2269",
       
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Conservative",
    currency: "GBP",
    allocations: [
      {
        id: "2241",
       
      },
      {
        id: "1175",
       
      },
      {
        id: "2300",
      
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Growth",
    currency: "GBP",
    allocations: [
      {
        id: "2241",
       
      },
      {
        id: "1175",
      
      },
      {
        id: "2269",
      
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Income",
    currency: "GBP",
    allocations: [
      {
        id: "2241",
       
      },
      {
        id: "1175",
      
      },
      {
        id: "2300",
       
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(a);

const trans = (a) => {
  const result =  a.reduce((pre, cur) => {
    const allocation = { [cur.name]: cur.allocations };
    return { ...pre, allocation };
  }, {});
  
  return result
};
const b = { US: trans(a) };

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Your expected output isn't valid.  US.allocation can either be an array or an object, but not a bunch of objects.

Comment: I suspect you intended to write `return { ...pre, ...allocation };` not `return { ...pre, allocation };`.

Comment: @RockySims , yes, but why this work? I originally want to what I really wrote, but it turned out it's not my desired output

Comment: `return { ...pre, allocation };` doesn't work because `allocation` is an object. You can't just add a value (like object) to another object. You have to specify both the key and the value when you add a value to an object.

Comment: Consider `const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2};` `const obj2 = {c: 3};` `const obj3 = {...obj1, obj2};`. This would seem to result in `obj3` being `{a: 1, b: 2, {c: 3}}` but the `{c: 3}` part is not valid because it doesn't have a key associated with it.

Comment: Thanks, it is very detailed, I guess I mix up with the situation in array (eg, const array2 =[...array1, newValue ] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've turned "US.allocation" into an object with property names like "Balanced", "Conservative" etc, with the appropriate allocations array as the property value.

```js
const a = [
  {
    name: "Balanced",
    allocations: [
      {
        id: "2241",

      },
      {
        id: "1175",
       
      },
      {
        id: "2269",
       
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Balanced Plus",
    currency: "GBP",
    allocations: [
      {
        id: "2238",
      
      },
      {
        id: "1175",
       
      },
      {
        id: "2269",
       
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Conservative",
    currency: "GBP",
    allocations: [
      {
        id: "2241",
       
      },
      {
        id: "1175",
       
      },
      {
        id: "2300",
      
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Growth",
    currency: "GBP",
    allocations: [
      {
        id: "2241",
       
      },
      {
        id: "1175",
      
      },
      {
        id: "2269",
      
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Income",
    currency: "GBP",
    allocations: [
      {
        id: "2241",
       
      },
      {
        id: "1175",
      
      },
      {
        id: "2300",
       
      },
    ],
  },
];

const b = {
  US: {
    allocation: Object.fromEntries(a.map(el => [el.name, el.allocations]))
  }
};

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, could you explain a bit the code in  allocation: Object.fromEntries(a.map(el => [el.name, el.allocations]))

Comment: The map converts your array `a` into an array of arrays containing "name" and "allocations" properties from `a`.  Object.fromEntries converts that array of arrays into an object.  [map docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) [fromEntries docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)